# Cassandra is going down frequently without any error or exception

Tags: server, cassandra

Cassandra is going down frequently in server, Checked for RAM and disk space. It's sufficient to run Cassandra. There is no error or exception in Cassandra logs file.
Cassandra version: 2.1.12

Comment: Check the system logs. Usually this sort of problem happens when Cassandra runs out of memory (you will see OOM handler invoked in the system log - assumptions about "sufficient RAM" are seldom correct :-).

Comment: Also, Cassandra 2.1.12 is like 5 years old.  There have been _so many_ bug fixes since then.  The 2.1.x line is no longer supported, but at the very least you should get on the last patch version released (2.1.21).  That might help things.

Answer (score 1):

If the messages in the logs stop abruptly, it's most likely the Linux `oom-killer` that is terminating the Cassandra process. You can see evidence of this in the operating system logs.

You didn't mention the Cassandra version but if:

- you're running C* 2.2 or newer
- node data size is greater than RAM

There's a chance that you're hitting a known issue where all SSTables are getting mapped to memory (with `mmap`). If this applies to your cluster, you will need to explicitly configure `disk_access_mode` to `mmap_index_only` so C* doesn't use up all the memory on the nodes.

I've explained the cause and solution in detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6947/. Cheers!